# magento 2 setup compile error

Tags: magento2, error, magento2-dev-beta, code-generation

In magento 2.0, when I run the `magento setup:di:compile` command, it gives an error:

> [ErrorException]
>     Declaration of Magento\Newsletter\Test\Unit\Model\Queue\TransportBuilderTes
>     t::testGetTransport() should be compatible with Magento\Framework\Mail\Test
>     \Unit\Template\TransportBuilderTest::testGetTransport($templateType, $messa
>     geType, $bodyText, $templateNamespace)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

For the moment change the

```
public function testGetTransport(
    $templateType = TemplateTypesInterface::TYPE_HTML,
    $messageType = MessageInterface::TYPE_HTML,
    $bodyText = '<h1>Html message</h1>'
)
```

to

```
public function testGetTransport(
    $templateType = TemplateTypesInterface::TYPE_HTML,
    $messageType = MessageInterface::TYPE_HTML,
    $bodyText = '<h1>Html message</h1>',
    $templateNamespace ='Magento\Newsletter\Test\Unit\Model\Queue'
)
```

in `app/code/Magento/Newsletter/Test/Unit/Model/Queue/TransportBuilderTest.php`

The string use for `$templateNamespace` can be probably wrong (however you can keep empty string if you want as this text is not using by the function)

Comment: For Magento2 release version, in /vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Test/Unit/Model/Queue/TransportBuilderTest.php